# node-RED port number

Tags: node.js, node-red

Can we set port number of node-RED is same with another port number?
ex: test.js is running on 1880 port number, and then node-RED port number is 1880 too. but httpRoot will be actived,so when I run the node-RED, I use 127.0.0.1:1880/red. Is it possible? 
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, two applications can not share a port like this directly.

You could use something like nginx running on port 1880 and run test.js and Node-RED on different ports and have nginx proxy requests to the separate applications.

Or you could look at the documentation for [embedding Node-RED](http://nodered.org/docs/embedding) and include Node-RED into your test.js application.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Im pretty sure you can, if you are listening on different interfaces.
So for example if you listen on eth0 port 80 for incoming requests to a program you could listen on port 80 on localhost (or eth2) for another program.

So if you can constrain the socket of both applications to listen on a specific (different) interface it will be ok.

Comment: The OP was asking about sharing the same port on the same/all interfaces and differentiating based on HTTP Path.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot use that port for Node-RED if its already being used. Run Node-RED using the following command:

```
node-red -p 1881
```

This will start Node-RED on a new port (1881), so whenever you want to use a new port, use this command as you can start multiple Node-RED services.